# Assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect' not compatible with Microsoft.Owin.Security

Tags: c#, owin, openid, identityserver3

I am trying to implement Identity Server 3 in my MVC application but I am getting following error at `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`

Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect' with identity 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' with identity 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Here is my Package.config File for relevant Error

```
 <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```